# How to merge similar lines in to one, if matches a string?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, tcl

I want to edit the given below file, the keywords are the first (0)/(1)/(2), etc and the `<STRING>` at last of line.

**If any two lines start with same number and has `[STRING]` in it then first line only should be kept, other should be deleted and append a comment at last of first line with "--- total_number_of_lines", as --- 2 or --- 3 or --- 4**

Please refer the below example for reference.

```
(0) some text let it be [STRING]
(0) some text1 let it be
(1) some text2 let it be 
(1) some text3 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text4 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text5 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text6 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text7 let it be [XYZ]
(0) some text8 let it be [STRING]
(0) some text9 let it be
(1) some text10 let it be 
(1) some text11 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text12 let it be [STRING]
(2) some text13 let it be [STRING]
(2) some text14 let it be [STRING]
(2) some text15 let it be [STRING]
(3) some text16 let it be [ABC]
(3) some text17 let it be [STRING]
(3) some text18 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text19 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text20 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text21 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text22 let it be [STRING]
(1) some text23 let it be [DEF]
```

This needs to be edited as:

```
(0) some text let it be [STRING]
(0) some text1 let it be
(1) some text2 let it be 
(1) some text3 let it be [STRING] --- 4
(1) some text7 let it be [XYZ]
(0) some text8 let it be [STRING]
(0) some text9 let it be
(1) some text10 let it be 
(1) some text11 let it be [STRING] --- 2
(2) some text13 let it be [STRING] --- 3
(3) some text16 let it be [ABC]
(3) some text17 let it be [STRING] --- 2
(1) some text19 let it be [STRING] --- 4 
(1) some text23 let it be [DEF]
```

Anybody has any suggestions? Corrected the questions to provide more clarity on the requirement.

Comment: Your posted expected output does not reflect your stated requirement. You say `If any two lines start with same number and has [STRING] in it then first line only should be kept, other should be deleted...` but in your output you have, for example, multiple occurrences of lines that start with `(1)` and have `[STRING]` in it, i.e.: `(1) some text3 let it be [STRING] --- 4` and `(1) some text11 let it be [STRING] --- 2` and `(1) some text19 let it be [STRING] --- 4`. Please update your question to clarify and correct whichever is wrong, the statement or requirements or your output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: For the changed requirements, this approach could be amended to

```
awk 'function tok() { return $0 ~ /\[STRING\]/ ? $1 : "" } function reset() { lastline = $0; prev = tok(); ctr = 1 } function commit() { print lastline (ctr == 1 ? "" : " --- " ctr); reset() } NR == 1 { reset(); next } !tok() || prev != tok() { commit(); next } { ++ctr } END { commit(); }'
```

The general approach is reading one block of lines ahead of writing. Blocks, including those consisting of only a single line, are printed after they have concluded. The code works as follows:

```
# Token for repetition detection: Lines that contain [STRING] are exempt,
# so for them we report an empty / no token.
function tok() {
  return $0 ~ /\[STRING\]/ ? $1 : ""
}

# reset counters etc. when a new block begins
function reset() {
  lastline = $0
  prev = tok()
  ctr = 1
}

# Write saved line, with counter if appropriate
function commit() {
  print lastline (ctr == 1 ? "" : " --- " ctr)
  reset()
}

# We write every block after it is over, and this includes single lines.
# So: First line, just prime the pump, do nothing else.
NR == 1 {
  reset()
  next
}

# If the new line is exempt (no token reported) or the token changed,
# print stuff, reprime pump.
!tok() || prev != tok() { 
  commit()
  next
}

# otherwise increase counter
{
  ++ctr
}

# and in the end, handle the last block.
END {
  commit()
}
```

Comment: Just changed the question by a bit....earlier it was not much clear on the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

The main tricky bit with solving this is to get the behaviour at the start of processing and the end of processing correct. Otherwise, it's just a matter of being able to keep a counter and compare with the previous line. Here's how to do it in Tcl:

```
# How to write out a line with an optional count; customise as necessary
proc writeLine {count line} {
     if {$count > 1} {
         puts "$line --- $count"
     } else {
         puts $line
     }
}

# Note that the prev variable is not set at this point

set count 0
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    # Extract the parts we care about
    if {[regexp {^(\(\d+\)).*(\[[^][]+\])$} $line -> a b]} {
        set AB $a$b
        if {[info exist prev] && $prevAB ne $AB} {
            writeLine $count $prev
            set count 0
            set prev $line
        } elseif {![info exist prev]} {
            set prev $line
        }
        set prevAB $AB
        incr count
    } else {
        # Unmatched line; flush and print
        if {[info exist prev]} {
            writeLine $count $prev
        }
        writeLine 1 $line
        set count 0
        unset -nocomplain prev prevAB
    }
}
# Print out the final line if necessary
if {[info exist prev]} {
    writeLine $count $prev
}
```

Comment: Just changed the question by a bit....earlier it was not much clear on the requirement.

Comment: @Star Printing the first of a group makes this deceptively tricky. And I recommend asking another question (linking back to the first so that it's clear it isn't a duplicate) when the first one is substantively misunderstood but still answered correctly _according to what is actually asked_…

Answer (score -1):

This does what your stated requirements say you want (`If any two lines start with same number and has [STRING] in it then first line only should be kept, other should be deleted and append a comment at last of first line with "--- total_number_of_lines", as --- 2 or --- 3 or --- 4`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { if (/\[STRING\]$/) cnt[$1]++; next }
/\[STRING\]$/ {
    if (seen[$1]++) next
    else $0 = $0 " --- " cnt[$1]
}
1

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
(0) some text let it be [STRING] --- 2
(0) some text1 let it be
(1) some text2 let it be
(1) some text3 let it be [STRING] --- 10
(1) some text7 let it be [XYZ]
(0) some text9 let it be
(1) some text10 let it be
(2) some text13 let it be [STRING] --- 3
(3) some text16 let it be [ABC]
(3) some text17 let it be [STRING] --- 2
(1) some text23 let it be [DEF]
```

but obviously that doesn't match your expected output because your expected output doesn't match your stated requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Another method is to use the unix "uniq" command. On the MacOS (BSD), it's:

```
uniq -c -s20
```

If you want to count the lines that are identical, excluding the first 20 characters from the comparison. That will put the count at the front. You can move the count to the end with:

```
uniq -c -s20 | sed -E 's/^ *([0-9]+) (.*)/\2 --- \1/g'
```

On unbuntu, it's sed -r, not sed -E.